# firestorm viewer, mirophone is gray

Tags: software-installation, microphone, libraries

Firestorm is installed and working, but the microphone remains grey. All of the settings look normal, except that the microphone is grayed out.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this thread pointed out that the voice call function requires a static 32bit binary named "SLVoice" to be running.
https://community.secondlife.com/forums/topic/475681-voice-problems/

and in the firestorm log we can see that this executable is not running

```
WARNING #Voice# newview/llvoicevivox.cpp(962) LLVivoxVoiceClient::callbackEndDaemon : SLVoice terminated {'data':i-1,'desc':'SLVoice (20101)','id':i20101,'state':i0,'string':'SLVoice (20101) exited with code -1'}
WARNING #Voice# newview/llvoicevivox.cpp(2044) LLVivoxVoiceClient::terminateAudioSession : terminateAudioSession(0) with NULL mAudioSession
```

#### how to troubleshoot

from inside your firestorm install, verify SLVoice can find all its dependencies using `ldd`

for example, on this system, libidn.so.11 is missing.

```
$ cd ~/Applications/Phoenix-Firestorm-Releasex64-6-6-17-70368/
$ ldd ./bin/SLVoice 
    linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7ede000)
    libortp.so => /home/user/Applications/Phoenix-Firestorm-Releasex64-6-6-17-70368/bin/../lib32/libortp.so (0xf7ea8000)
    libsndfile.so.1 => /home/user/Applications/Phoenix-Firestorm-Releasex64-6-6-17-70368/bin/../lib32/libsndfile.so.1 (0xf7e4f000)
    libvivoxsdk.so => /home/user/Applications/Phoenix-Firestorm-Releasex64-6-6-17-70368/bin/../lib32/libvivoxsdk.so (0xf7800000)
    libvivoxplatform.so => /home/user/Applications/Phoenix-Firestorm-Releasex64-6-6-17-70368/bin/../lib32/libvivoxplatform.so (0xf7702000)
    libvivoxoal.so.1 => /home/user/Applications/Phoenix-Firestorm-Releasex64-6-6-17-70368/bin/../lib32/libvivoxoal.so.1 (0xf76b4000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xf7665000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xf7660000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0xf764d000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf7648000)
    libidn.so.11 => not found
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0xf763e000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7639000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf7400000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf72f8000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf72d1000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf7000000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7ee0000)
    libidn.so.11 => not found
    libidn.so.11 => not found
    libidn.so.11 => not found
```

check if we can install it with apt-file
`$ apt-file search libidn.so.11` - no results, check again for `$ apt-file search libidn.so`

pulls up a couple results

```
$ apt-file search libidn.so
libidn-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so
libidn12: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.12
libidn12: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.12.6.3
```

(ps
enable the i386 architecture
if not already ,its required to run 32-bit executable.

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
```

)

on this system, I wasn't sure what source release of libidn mapped to "12", so I checked repology,
https://repology.org/project/libidn/versions
who's records show <s>various systems linking the latest libidn as "libidn12", but importantly, that same latest version was linked as "libidn11" (by Cygwin). which indicates that the ABI might not have changed so drastically between 11 and 12 that they became incompatible, usually that's what a version increase implies. YMMV. I chose not to recompile libidn from source for this system at this time and tried a hack of linking libidn.11 to libidn.so.12. there are various ways to do this but it isn't recommended and can break your system so you can DIY it from here.</s>

an incomplete example, we could use LD_LIBRARY_PATH to add ./foo-i386-linux-gnu/ to the linker path `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD/foo-i386-linux-gnu/`, and link *the 32 bit* version of libidn.so.12 as ./foo-i386-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11, and inject LD_LIBRARY_PATH before starting firestorm like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD/foo-i386-linux-gnu/ ./firestorm`

on this system that appeared to work, but it would always be more appropriate to build the version SLVoice expects from source and install that as libidn.so.11

https://repology.org/project/libidn/versions
also shows that the majority of systems used libidn 1.33 to provider libidn.so.11 so here is an example of compiling this and adding it to firestorm yourself

```
$ cd Phoenix-Firestorm-Releasex64-6-6-17-70368
# prepare working directory
$ mkdir devel
$ cd devel

# acquite libidn 1.33
$ https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libidn/libidn-1.33.tar.gz
$ tar -xvzf libidn-1.33.tar.gz
$ cd libidn-1.33/

# prepare out of tree build (as subdirectory) for i386 lib
$ mkdir build32
$ cd build32

# (note, you may need a compiler first)
#sudo apt-get install build-essential

$ ../configure --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu CFLAGS=-m32 CXXFLAGS=-m32 LDFLAGS=-m32
$ make

# install build artifacts to staging directory ./prefix, you can `sudo make
# install` or replace DESTDIR with any other preffered system root, or
# configure the build with a different --prefix
# this is fine
$ make install DESTDIR=$PWD/prefix/
# locate the produced dll
$ fine ./prefix/ | grep -i libidn.so
# link (here symbolic but you could also hard link, or copy)
$ ln -sr ./prefix/usr/local/lib/libidn.so.11 ../../../lib32/
# verify firestorm picks up this new library, if not, you might have the wrong --build architecture
$ ldd ../../../bin/SLVoice
    linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7f12000)
    libortp.so => /home/user/Applications/Phoenix-Firestorm-Releasex64-6-6-17-70368/b/libidn-1.33/build32/../../../bin/../lib32/libortp.so (0xf7edc000)
    libsndfile.so.1 => /home/user/Applications/Phoenix-Firestorm-Releasex64-6-6-17-70368/b/libidn-1.33/build32/../../../bin/../lib32/libsndfile.so.1 (0xf7e83000)
    libvivoxsdk.so => /home/user/Applications/Phoenix-Firestorm-Releasex64-6-6-17-70368/b/libidn-1.33/build32/../../../bin/../lib32/libvivoxsdk.so (0xf7800000)
    libvivoxplatform.so => /home/user/Applications/Phoenix-Firestorm-Releasex64-6-6-17-70368/b/libidn-1.33/build32/../../../bin/../lib32/libvivoxplatform.so (0xf7702000)
    libvivoxoal.so.1 => /home/user/Applications/Phoenix-Firestorm-Releasex64-6-6-17-70368/b/libidn-1.33/build32/../../../bin/../lib32/libvivoxoal.so.1 (0xf76b4000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xf7696000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xf7e4d000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0xf7681000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf767c000)
    libidn.so.11 => /home/user/Applications/Phoenix-Firestorm-Releasex64-6-6-17-70368/b/libidn-1.33/build32/../../../bin/../lib32/libidn.so.11 (0xf7646000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0xf763c000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7637000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf7400000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf72f8000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf72d1000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf7000000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7f14000)
```

closing notes, libidn was an extremely well-behaved and easy to use library to install from source.